# What video production softwares are typically used for the following

Tags: animation

This may be a subjective question, but I'm not sure where else to ask, so apologies in advance!

A lot of websites for softwares of various kinds have marketing videos of user-interfaces in action.  These aren't the actual ui's that have been recorded -- they are instead "faux-ui's" that are simplified and usually more animated versions of the real thing.

eg:

https://a.slack-edge.com/5f6f2/marketing/img/homepage/hp-prospect/channels/bring-your-team-together-in-channels.mp4

https://www.helpscout.com/

I am wondering:  What kinds of video softwares are typically used for the production of these?  Are there are certain tools that are industry standard for this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether there is specific software that does this but my go-to would be after effects as it allows you to build all this within itself, or it can animate a file that was build in photoshop/illustrator